# Django haystack querying database

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am having this weird issue while referring to a specific field on the view, django makes a SQL query, although it a haystack index.

search_indexes.py

```
class StoreIndex(indexes.ModelSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)        
    city = indexes.CharField(model_attr='city__name', faceted=True)
    region = indexes.CharField(model_attr='region__name', faceted=True)
    country = indexes.CharField(model_attr='country__name')
    created_at = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='created_at')
    tags = indexes.MultiValueField(model_attr='tags__names', faceted=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Store

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(created_at__lte=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

urls.py

```
queryset = SearchQuerySet().facet('tags').facet('region').facet('city')

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
                   url(r'^search', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=queryset),
                       name='haystack_search'),
                   )
```

results.html

```
<!-- Begin results. -->
        <div id="search-results">
            <ul>
            {% for result in page.object_list %}
                {% include 'search/_result_object.html' %}
                {% empty %}
                <p>No results found.</p>
            {% endfor %}               
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- End results. -->
```

_result_object.html

```
{% with object=result.object %}
<li class="search-result">
<section>
    <h3>{{ object.name }}</h3>
    <p>{{ object.addressLine1 }}, {{ object.addressLine2 }}, {{ object.addressLine3 }}   </p>
    <strong> {{ object.city }}, {{ object.region }} </strong>
    <strong class="pull-right"><a href="{% url 'store_detail' pk=object.id %}">Details</a></strong>
</section>
</li>
{% endwith %}
```

It queries database when accessing {{ object.city }}, {{ object.region }}

I have verified, both city and region get stored in elasticsearch as proper names.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use any of the `result.object.*` fields it will do a DB lookup and hit your SQL database.
Try eg. `result.city` directly, that should use the data from the index and avoid the SQL DB hit.

Comment: Thanks. just changed to {% with object=result %} and <strong class="pull-right"><a href="{% url 'store_detail' pk=object.pk %}">Details</a></strong>.

Comment: If you need to get the objects from the DB but don't want to do a query each time, you can do e.g. `p_ids = [a.pk for a in results]` and then do e.g. `Photo.objects.filter(id__in=p_ids)`. This only works if you use a Haystack query that returns results from only one model, e.g. `r = SearchQuerySet().models(Photo).filter(text="Something here")`